# Anyone knows how do i export more than one proyect to my Android physical phone? When i export 1 of my 2 different apps I replace everything :(

Tags: android, angular, android-studio, ionic-framework, capacitor

My 2nd proyect replaces my 1st proyect which has other icon, name, etc. I don't know why. I tried changing "appId" for it's proper name. (By default was "com.example.app in both proyects). So i replaced "example" for each name but it didn't work. :(
I couldn't find any video or documentation to fix this.
Thanks!
(Im using Angular - Ionic - Capacitor) for a native mobile app. (Using Android Studio).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzLvM.png

Btw. Im using my real physical phone to test this 2 apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. I had just to delete "android" folder and add it again by using

npx cap add android

then just play the app and i won't replace other of your apps. :)